# W3 validation error "content" "charset"

Tags: html

I've run into these 2 problems on my site. I've already fixed allot, but can't fix those. I hope there's someone that can help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"  />

<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="images/animated_favicon1.gif" />
<link href="opmaak.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Leerling 123</title>
</head>
<body>
<table summary="" class="hoofdtabel">
<tr>
  <td class="kop" colspan="2">Leerling 123</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="menu">
  <a href="home.html" target="inhoud" class="button">Home</a><br /><br />
  <a href="overmij.html" target="inhoud" class="button">Over mij</a><br /><br />
  <a href="hobby.html" target="inhoud" class="button">Hobby's</a><br /><br />
  <a href="foto.html" target="inhoud" class="button">Foto's</a><br /><br />
  <a href="video.html" target="inhoud" class="button">Video</a><br /><br />
  <a href="geluidsopname.html" target="inhoud" class="button">Geluidsopname</a><br /><br />
  <a href="rooster.html" target="inhoud" class="button">Rooster</a><br /><br />
 </td>
  <td class="inhoud">
   <iframe class="frame" src="home.html" name="inhoud"></iframe>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="onder" colspan="2">
  <a href="copyright.html" target="inhoud">Copyright</a>
  <a href="disclaimer.html" target="inhoud">Disclaimer</a>
  <a href="sitemap.html" target="inhoud">Sitemap</a> 
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

> Error Line 4, Column 24: required attribute "content" not specified
>
> `<meta charset="utf-8" />`
>
> ✉
>
> The attribute given above is required for an element that you've used, but you have omitted it. For instance, in most HTML and XHTML document types the "type" attribute is required on the "script" element and the "alt" attribute is required for the "img" element.
>
> Typical values for type are type="text/css" for `<style>` and type="text/javascript" for `<script>`.
>
> Error Line 4, Column 15: there is no attribute "charset"
>       
>   ✉
>   You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the document type you are using does not support that attribute for this element. This error is often caused by incorrect use of the "Strict" document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute), or by using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this is usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).
>
> This error may also result if the element itself is not supported in the document type you are using, as an undefined element will have no supported attributes; in this case, see the element-undefined error message for further information.
>
> How to fix: check the spelling and case of the element and attribute, (Remember XHTML is all lower-case) and/or check that they are both allowed in the chosen document type, and/or use CSS instead of this attribute. If you received this error when using the  element to incorporate flash media in a Web page, see the FAQ item on valid flash.

Comment: @L.Guthardt but not completely

Comment: But the error was not the favico image

Comment: @L.Guthardt “the existence of this question is not valid. Since there is already enough knowledge out there” — the existence of the question is evidence that there is actually not already enough knowledge out there.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Hmm, agreed. In this case, but you can transfer this statement to every SO question, since quite a few newcomer's questions lack of proper quality content and earlier research on that topic.

Comment: Anyway, I marked it duplicate and deleted my answer

Comment: Please stop using transitional doctypes! They were useful somewhere in 1998-2001, where smooth "transitioning" from HTML3.2 to HTML4 and its XML reformulation, XHTML1, seemed a reasonable thing to do. But now you don't use HTML3.2 elements like `<basefont>` and `<font>` anyway, so you have nothing to "transition" from, and these doctypes do nothing good, they only mess up the validators and breake some CSS functionality because of the "limited quirks mode" they turn on in browsers.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn I'm sorry, I'm really new to HTML, I've just learned the very basics. What should I place instead of font, which you said isn't reccomended to use?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I'm sorry. I already saw that other answer but wasn't bright enough to figure out that was the answer. Thanks for your old answer though. It fixed the problem :)

Comment: Just use `<!DOCTYPE html>` then you can keep your charset

Comment: @Thom: it seems that you started to learn HTML by a rather old reference, which seems to focus on syntax (XHTML syntax, particularly, which isn't much relevant nowadays) while missing some important things like document structuring. I'd recommend to use more modern sources, like the [introduction to HTML on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML). And don't ignore CSS, too!